# Installing VisualSVN when Apache is already installed

Tags: apache-2.2, visualsvn-server

Is there any way I can install VisualSVN not installing Apache?

The thing is that I already have Apache installed in the same server, so I want VisualSVN to use that Apache installation.

By the way: I was told that VisualSVN is the best (easyest) alternative for installing SVN in Windows Server. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst VisualSVN is one of the easiest ways of installing SVN on Windows, it does, as you say, install Apache with it.

When it installs Apache, you can do so on a different port and location to your existing Apache installation, so you could run the two side by side. That said, if you really don't want another version of Apache, then you will need to install and configure SVN manually to work with your own version of Apache. [This article](http://svn.spears.at/) provides a good guide on doing so.